# D3: show years on first month and on January, and move ticks to bar midpoints

Tags: d3.js

Consider the following:

**page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 -->
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

// load .csv file
d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });
    x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);

    //console.log(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data));

    // the bars 
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", (width - margin.right- margin.left)/data.length );

    // x-axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


});
</script>

</body>
```

**test_data.csv**:

```
date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575
```

We obtain the following output:

[image]
I would like to do two things:

1. Shift the axis to the right slightly so that the ticks for each month are at the midpoint of every bar. The axis should still extend from the beginning of the first bar to the end of the last bar; the ticks are just shifted.
2. Show the value of the year under the month label for first tick (in this case, Nov 2012) and under every occurrence of "Jan."

**I don't necessarily need a detailed solution; just knowing where to look would be great.**

Comment: @AndrewReid That's helpful, thank you! The only problem with that is that the x-axis no longer extends to the ends of the graph... I'll look into this more.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's why I removed the comment - If I had seen a response I would have left it. However, you can see in your image that the axis doesn't extent the full way as it is. *(For reference, the original comment was to nudge the axis by half a bar's width modifying the translation used to position the axis -  `.attr("transform", "translate(+ barWidth/2 + "," + height + ")")` )*

Comment: @AndrewReid Hmm, you're right (on the right side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue you face is that your x domain does not reflect how you draw your data. Because you draw your bars as being one month wide, your domain extends one extra month past your end point (it doesn't end November 1, it ends November 30). This is why the end part of your axis (the domain line) is not drawn.

Put another way, the maximum value in the domain is at the edge of the plot area. If you look carefully, you might notice that the last bar is plotted in the margin - it extends from the maximum svg x value of the plot area, and consequently, extends past the axis.

This is a  key challenge in using a time scale with bars, any point on the axis is merely a point - while you represent these points as having width - and your scale only extends from the start point to the end point. If you want to keep a time scale, you need to extend your domain to account for the last bar's width. Since your data points represent months, you need to extend your x scale domain by one month:

```
x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

var max = x.domain()[1]; // get the maximum date in the domain
var min = x.domain()[0]; // get the minimum date in the domain

var newMax = new Date(); 

newMax.setTime(max.getTime() + 29.99 * 86400000); // set a new max date for the end of November, see Gerardo's comment below for a better way to calculate dates. However, adding a full month may add a new month label to the chart. Removing it though, isn't that difficult.

x.domain([min,newMax]) // set the new domain.
```

*The logic for this might change depending on the number of days in the month you are terminating on.*

You should also change the bar width accordingly:

```
var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1)
```

Now you need to adjust the ticks. The tick marks a point in time on the scale, and as you place your bars to have their x position based on that point, you need to move the ticks to the right by half the bars' width. You can do so with:

```
var axis = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

axis.selectAll("g").select("text")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + ( (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1)/2 ) + ",0)");
```

This should give you something like:

[image]

See [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/0a7f6d51a8d891a26c389f53122a1440).

I've left the ticks lines where they were, you can translate them as well if you want, but you will need to remove either the first or last one as you need one less tick than you have bars.

You are asking two different questions here, so I'll offer a quick suggestion for showing the years, use a second x axis, show ticks every year and format it to show the year (same as  you do for months). Just be sure to position it lower (you might need more margin on the bottom). Remove the domain line and remove (or format) the tick lines.

Comment: My dear Andrew, why are you bending backwards with that strange math to add a month? You can simplify it! Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/79511cqf/ Not only this is simpler, but it takes into account February, months with 30/31 days, leap years, daylight savings changes etc...

Comment: Ah, very nice, I figured there was some d3 function for this that I was missing, thanks for pointing it out - I'm not sure if I have seen it in use before.

Comment: No worries, +1 anyway. However, if I were answering this, I'd just say to the OP: *"Do **not** use bars with a time scale"*. That's the incorrect use of a bar chart: bar charts have to use **categorical** variables. That's why a histogram is not a bar chart, even if both have *bars*.

Comment: I'd agree with that statement, and I expected you to notice the use of bars with a time scale - I probably could have been more explicit about the problems of using bars with time.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado For the record, I agree with both of you; however, I'm just building in D3 what has already been built in a... let's say, not open-source program.